# Group in AD, which will include all users who have a mailing address

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

I need to create a group in AD, which will include all users who have a mailing address on our Exchange Server.

How to select such users and add them to the group?
I suppose to run such a script periodically (for example, once a week) to keep up to date.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of Exchange Mangement Shell, Pure AD Powershell and a Exchange Dynamic Distribution Group if you only need it for Mailinglist purposes.

Here are the first 2 ways as mentioned.

**Exchange Management Shell Version** (assuming that how to connect to EMS is known.):

```
# Set the AD group name
$ADGroupName = "GroupName"  # Replace with the desired name for the AD group

# Connect to the Exchange Server
# <connection code here>

# Get the users with mailing addresses
$UsersWithMailingAddresses = Get-Mailbox | Where-Object { $_.EmailAddresses -like "*SMTP:*" }
    
# Create the AD group
# Skip this step if Group is already present
#New-ADGroup -Name $ADGroupName -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Global -DisplayName $ADGroupName -Path "OU=Groups,DC=YourDomain,DC=com"

# Add users to the AD group
foreach ($User in $UsersWithMailingAddresses) {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $ADGroupName -Members $User.SamAccountName
}

# Close the Exchange Server session
# Remove-PSSession $Session
```

**AD PowerShell Module Version:**

```
# Set the AD group name
$ADGroupName = "GroupName"  # Replace with the desired name for the AD group

# Set the attribute to filter users
$Attribute = "mail"

# Set the filter value
$FilterValue = "*"

# Get the users with the specified attribute
$UsersWithAttribute = Get-ADUser -Filter "$Attribute -like '$FilterValue'"

# Create the AD group
# Skip this step if Group is already present
#New-ADGroup -Name $ADGroupName -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Global -DisplayName $ADGroupName -Path "OU=Groups,DC=YourDomain,DC=com"

# Add users to the AD group
foreach ($User in $UsersWithAttribute) {
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $ADGroupName -Members $User.SamAccountName
}
```